# How to change the name on a button dynamically using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my code:

```
<button id="btnajs" ng-click="AppendText()">Using angularjs</button>
<div id="divID"></div>
<script>
var count=1;
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.AppendText = function() {
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     myEl.append("<tr><td><button type='submit' name='id_"+count+"' class='newbtn' id='"+count+"' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>{{bn}}</button></td></tr>");  
     count++;   
    }

}

var myapp=angular.module("myapp",[]);

myapp.controller('btncontrol',function($scope){
   $scope.bn="Save data";

   $scope.save=function(){
    $scope.bn= "Saving data...";


};
});

</script>
```

The button "angular js" is to be clicked and then more buttons are appended below it.. i want to be able to change the names of those appended buttons
to "save data" and after clicking on the same button change to "saving data..", but it only appears as {{bn}}.
I have added all the necessary libraries.

Comment: I am sorry..i think i didn't explain my problem correctly.I have made a few edits.. explaining what i want..

Answer (score 1):

**How about something like that**

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {});
app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
    <span ng-show="toggle">Save Data</span>
    <span ng-hide="toggle">Saving Data</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use jquery way,

Just change the scope variable on button click using function.

```
 $scope.AppendText = function(){
     $scope.bn = "saving data";
 }
```

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
   $scope.bn = "Save data";
    $scope.AppendText = function(){
      $scope.bn = "saving data";
    }
  }

]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <button ng-click="AppendText()"> {{bn}}</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use $scope.save in this code. Also write the html part seperate.  if you want to code exactly as yours. please call save() in myEl.append.